# Domain names assigned with IP

Tags: dns, ip, icann

I have a doubt on how domain names are assigned to IP address.

According to ICANN evey domain will be assigned to IP address which will be globally accessed.

Lets say there are 3 different domains hosted on 1 reseller account

```
"example.com"
"example.org"
"againexample.com"
```

If we query this domains for there IP address, we get same IP address!

How is it possible?

It should be different IP address for each right?

Can anybody explain the login here?

Answer (score 1):

When you type in address `www.example.com` in your browser, a request is sent to DNS (Domain Name Server). DNS Server responds with the IP address associated with that domain.

Your browser then sends a request to the server located at the IP address provided, which then, based on domain requested, server appropriate content.

Basically, on the server side, it is configured as follows:

```
example.com -> /var/www/example.com/
otherdomain.example -> /var/www/otherdomain.example/
admin.example -> /var/www/admin/
```

Which means, for the requested domain, serve content from the specified folder. For example if you type `example.com` you will get site located in `/var/www/example.com/`.

Comment: You mean, Browser request ICANN DNS server to domain IP, and the IP we get here is reseller ip not domain ip right?

Comment: DNS servers are not owned by ICANN. In fact, they work more in a "pyramid" scheme. First dns is most likely your local dns cache in your router, then after it comes dns from your ISP, then after then your ISP has it's ISP, etc. So when you type 'google.com' for example, if the IP is cached in your dns cache (on your computer or your router) you will get it from there. If not, your router will ask it from your ISP, which (if it does not know) will ask further. What you get as a response is an IP address of a server where the site is located. Nobody said that one server can have only one site.

Answer (score 0):

You are using shared hosting, what means you will share the server with other websites. If you need a dedicated IP adres, you should ask your webhosting provider to assign several different IP adreses to your websites. Usually you have to pay extra for this.